About Kali Purusha and Asuras
In this chapter of Vana Parva, the Asuras revealing to Duryodhana that he was created by Lord Shiva and Parvati.

O exalted king, know the truth, the celestial origin of thy soul, and the maker of thy body, and then summon thou patience to thy aid. In days of old. O king, we have obtained thee, by ascetic austerities from Maheswara. The upper part of thy body is wholly made of an assemblage of Vajras, and is, therefore, invulnerable to weapons of every description, O sinless one. The lower part of thy body, capable of captivating the female heart by its comeliness was made of flowers by the goddess herself--the wife of Mahadeva. Thy body is thus, O best of kings, the creation of Maheswara himself and his goddess.

It's actually implies Kali Purusha is created by Shiva-Parvati for Asuras. But, what is relation between him and the Asuras? Is it mentiones directly or indirectly on any scripture?

Huh. To me it seems to me like Kali Purusha (among the asuras) incarnated as Suyodhana/Duryodhana with the vajra upper body, after the asuras performed penance to Uma-Maheshwara for the boon of him getting that special abillity.

@K.V.Sharma But, if Duryodhana's body is invincible to any weapon, how can he overpowered by Bhima's mace? And, the asuras are also says "days of old" and describes Duryodhana as "divine", which akin to the mention of Kali Purusha as "the vilest among celestial" in Nalopakhyana Parva. So, in my opinion, it's Kali Purusha, not Duryodhana.
